# Better way of checking if socket is connected or disconnected using OkHttp?

Tags: android, sockets, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp for sending and receiving messages through socket on Android.

Creating a socket connection -

```
SocketListener listener = new SocketListener();

mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(socketURL)
    .build();
mOkHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, listener);
```

And this is the SocketListener class that is used to listen to all the web socket events -

```
public final class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener { 
    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
       // doing something
       isSocketConnected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
       // doing something
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
       // doing something
       isSocketConnected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
       isSocketConnected = false;
    }

}
```

Sometimes the socket connection drops and as you can see, I'm using **isSocketConnected** variable on SocketListener class to keep track of 'if socket is connected or disconnected'.

Can there be a better way to check if the socket is connected or disconnected ?

Comment: Any updates on the same?

Comment: no updates. I didn't find a better way. If someone finds, please post an answer.

Comment: there is a better way now. check the answer given by @Alexey below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Tinder Scarlet method to solve by using Rx

```
internal class OkHttpWebSocketEventObserver : WebSocketListener() {
    private val processor = PublishProcessor.create<WebSocket.Event>().toSerialized()

    fun observe(): Flowable<WebSocket.Event> = processor

    fun terminate() = processor.onComplete()

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: okhttp3.WebSocket, response: Response) =
        processor.onNext(WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened(webSocket))

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: okhttp3.WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) =
        processor.onNext(WebSocket.Event.OnMessageReceived(Message.Bytes(bytes.toByteArray())))

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: okhttp3.WebSocket, text: String) =
        processor.onNext(WebSocket.Event.OnMessageReceived(Message.Text(text)))

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: okhttp3.WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) =
        processor.onNext(WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionClosing(ShutdownReason(code, reason)))

    override fun onClosed(webSocket: okhttp3.WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) =
        processor.onNext(WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionClosed(ShutdownReason(code, reason)))

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: okhttp3.WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) =
        processor.onNext(WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionFailed(t))
}
```

Comment: this is more structured. also saw the scarlet library. I can now dig more in the library to get more info. Thanks.

Comment: By Rx do you mean ReactiveX?

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer

```
private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, okhttp3.Response response) {
        isSocketConnected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        //you code
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        isSocketConnected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, okhttp3.Response response) {
            isSocketConnected = false;
            createSocket(); // reopen socket
    }

}
```

and this connection code

```
if (isSocketConnected == false) {
                SocketListener listener = new SocketListener();

                mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(socketURL)
                        .build();
                mOkHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, listener);
            }
```

I hope this help

Comment: My question is not about when to start a new connection. Please go through the question.